# How to assign a variable in bash without using $?

Tags: bash

Is there any easier/more elegant way to assign a return value to a variable? So far I've been doing something like:

```
some_command_to_run
VAR_TO_SET=$?
```

But I would much prefer to have it all on one line and preferably without using the $? variable. Does anyone know how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That is all I know as well.  However, if you are just doing this repeatily to see if I command was sucessful with something like:

```
if [[ $? -ne 0 ]]; then
   ...
fi
```

You can actually just test a command directory like:

```
if ! mkdir foo; then
   ...
fi
```

You might have already know that, but figured it *might* help you :-)

Comment: In fact, if you're doing this repeatedly, you're probably looking for `set -e`, which tells the shell to stop processing the script immediately if a command returns nonzero. If one particular command may legitimately fail, a common idiom is `command_that_may_fail || true`.

Answer (score 5):

The question I have is "Why?". It's the facility provided by Bash to accomplish that function.

However, you can do this (in addition to what Kyle and Gilles showed):

```
do_something && do_on_success || do_on_failure
```

Comment: Yeah, I second the "why"... there might be a reasonable question here :)

Answer (score 4):

That's all there is. If you really want it on one line, you can write `some_command_to_run; VAR_TO_SET=$?`. You could make it a two-liner function, but I don't recommend it because it will make your scripts less readable (one more thing to learn to be able to understand your code).